# Java KeyEvent JUST ALT

Tags: java, key-bindings

I want to be able to (in a JPanel - I'm using KeyBindings for arrow keys and ALT + KeyEvent.VK_lots_of_different_keys) press ALT (and only ALT) and know when it is pressed so I can drag the mouse around and stop it from performing other things that should not happen when alt is pressed.

Is there a KeyEvent for this or a work-around? (I have tried the various (4) ALT key masks, but those obviously don't work).

some code:

```
altPressed = false;

InputMap inMap = getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
ActionMap actMap = getActionMap();

KeyStroke pressed = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ALT, 0, false);
KeyStroke released = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_ALT, 0, true);

inMap.put(pressed, "alt" + "pressed");
inMap.put(released, "alt" + "released");

actMap.put("alt" + "pressed", new AbstractAction () {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        altPressed = true;
    }
});

actMap.put("alt" + "released", new AbstractAction () {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        altPressed = false;
    }
});

private class KeyListener implements ActionListener {//... yada yada yada ...
    @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {// check if keys are pressed and perform proper actions....
...
...
}

Timer timer = new Timer(100, new KeyListener());
timer.start();
```

Comment: Ooooop.. I found it. VK_ALT. silly me... except that doesn't work either

Comment: Are you trying to detect if the Alt button is pressed while clicking/dragging/etc. with the mouse?

Comment: @PM77-1 I'm working on it right now, but it's seriously a pain in the butt. All of my other keys work. Why do you need code? I'm using (JPanel).getInputMap and getActionMap and putting everything in the SAME EXACT WAY (in a for loop). I know it's right. It's just not working.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Yes. When in MouseListener check (when `mousePressed() {}`) if alt is pressed. I was attempting to do this with Key Bindings. I tried VK_ALT with no mask, but it didn't work like the rest of my keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you trying to detect if the Alt button is pressed while clicking/dragging/etc. with the mouse, you can use the [`getModifiersEx()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseEvent.html#getModifiersEx--) method of `MouseEvent`. The `MouseEvent` object will be sent to your listener in each of the methods of the `MouseInputListener` impelementation.

Comment: I'm using MouseMotionListener, MouseListener and MouseWheelListener. I don't know how that would work

Comment: @Dylan `MouseInputListener` is just a convenience interface which extends both `MoustMotionListener` and `MouseListener`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Oh, ok. I think I understand.  With e.getModifiersEx() and thennn... I'm not too familiar with this. Something with a bit-wise and I think... ?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I didn't really know what I was doing (I just learned about key bindings in the recent two months), but I DID IT; YOU did it. Thanks so much.